# FSharp.Core for Windows Phone 7.1 and F# 3.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, f#, portable-class-library, f#-3.0

The F# 2.0 distribution had a version of FSharp.Core compiled for WindowsPhone 7.1/Silverlight 4, but F# 3.0 doesn't, and the portable version only supports Silverlight 5 or Windows Phone 8. Has anyone been able to compile a version of FSharp.Core for F# 3.0 targeting Silverlight 4 or Windows Phone 7.1 from source? What are the defines required?

**Edit:**

On the fsharp compiler github repo, there's a target named portable-net4+sl4+wp71+win8, but in reality that's portable class library Profile47, which supposedly only support .NET 4.5, Silverlight 5.0 and Windows Store apps. It's the same as what's installed with VS2012. If you try to use it with a WP 7.1 project, it will fail at runtime complaining about missing IStructuralEquatable. It should really be named portable-net45+sl5+win8. There's a wp7 target also in the proj files, but it's currently not compiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got both the wp7 target and Portable88 target compiling from F# source after a couple of changes https://github.com/ovatsus/fsharp

Still need to thoroughly test at runtime, though

Answer (score 3):

I managed to compile it, but since I don't normally use F#, I don't know how to test it. Have you followed the instructions for compiling? Just type the following commands in the VS Developer Prompt

```
cd src
msbuild fsharp-proto-build.proj
msbuild fsharp-library-build.proj
msbuild fsharp-compiler-build.proj
msbuild fsharp-library-build.proj /p:TargetFramework=portable-net4+sl4+wp71+win8
```

Note that I did it with Visual Studio 2012 Professional. If you want, I can send you compiled dll and you can try it.

Comment: Altough it's labeled portable-net4+sl4+wp71+win8 in the fsharp compiler proj files, it's Profile47, which doesn't work in wp71, it fails at runtime complaining about missing IStructuralEquatable. It should really be named portable-net45+sl5+win8. There's a wp7 target also in the proj files, but it's currently failing with duplicate mscorlib references

Comment: Aaah, my bad. I'll see what I can do over the weekend.