# Using a custom version of FSharp.Core.dll

Tags: f#, mono, portable-class-library

I've been poking around with the fsharp compiler source code to try to build a wp7 version of FSharp.Core ([FSharp.Core for Windows Phone 7.1 and F# 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694577/fsharp-core-for-windows-phone-7-1-and-f-3-0)), and at one point I gave up and started trying to make the portable version work with wp7 instead. I added the `FX_NO_STRUCTURAL_EQUALITY` define to the `portable-net4+sl4+wp71+win8` target framework, which seems to what's causing it to not work at runtime, and tried to replace the FSharp.Core.dll in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\.NETPortable` with my custom version. But I get this errors when compiling in Visual Studio:

```
Warning 1   The primary reference "FSharp.Core" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile47". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "FSharp.Core" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  1578    5   FSharp.Data.Portable
Warning 3   The primary reference "FSharp.Core" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile47". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "FSharp.Core" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  1578    5   FSharp.Data.Portable
Warning 2   The primary reference "FSharp.Core" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile47". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "FSharp.Core" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets  1578    5   FSharp.Data.Portable
```

The problem is that the portable FSharp.Core that comes with VS2012 depends on the portable 2.0.5.0 versions of mscorlib.dll, System.dll and System.Core.dllthose assemblies, but the one I compile from source depends on the non-portable 4.0.0.0 versions. Has anyone built the portable version successfully from source?

Comment: you could try adding an app.config with bindingRedirect, e.g. http://apollo13cn.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/f-powerpack-with-dev11-preview.html

Comment: Neither Silverlight or WindowsPhone support assembly redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the portable-net4+sl4+wp71+win8 target compiling to Profile88 from F# source after a couple of changes https://github.com/ovatsus/fsharp

Still need to thoroughly test at runtime, though

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is add:

`<OtherFlags>$(OtherFlags) --simpleresolution -r:"pathToTheCorrectmscorlib/mscorlib-runtime.dll"  </OtherFlags>`

to the `FSharp.Source.Targets` file.  Do this right file after the `<DefineConstants>` elements.  This should cause the compilation phase to use the version of `mscorlib` that you specify rather than the default version specified by the msbuild target.  (Obviously replace `pathToTheCorrectmscorlib/mscorlib-runtime.dll` with the correct one :) )

Comment: I've added that for mscorlib, System and System.Core, but still having problems. Latest one is `A reference to the type 'System.Collections.Concurrent.Partitioner'1' in assembly 'mscorlib' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly`, but I can't find a reference to it anywhere

Comment: Thats from the Array.Parallel stuff in TPL

Comment: Only one I have seen similar is:  FX_NO_CONCURRENT_DICTIONARY.  Thats used in QueryExtensions.fs  and FX_NO_TPL_PARALLEL, which is in Async and Array definitions.

Comment: Is this in your Fsharp.Data build?  Do you have a repo with it failing in?

Comment: If you try use the portable library build of FSharp.Data on a windows phone 7 project it will fail to run complaining about the IStructuralEquatable. But I'm just trying to compile Profile88 form the fsharp.core source and trying it on a blank windowsphone project. I'll put the repo on github and let you know

Comment: I started from scratch doing smaller steps, but I can't even open the project in VS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935479/missing-targeting-pack-for-netframework-version-v4-0-profile-profile47