# Missing targeting pack for ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile47"

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

I've been having some problems when trying to compile the [portable version of FSharp.Core from the f# source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791925/using-a-custom-version-of-fsharp-core-dll).

To help with this, I created some project files to be able to open it inside Visual Studio instead of having to use the following command:

```
msbuild fsharp-library-build.proj /p:TargetFramework=portable-net4+sl4+wp71+win8
```

When I open `FSharp.Core.Portable.sln` from [here](https://github.com/ovatsus/fsharp), I get this very weird error:

[image: Error]

There is no such targeting pack for VS2012, [it's supposed to come out of the box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/hh487283.aspx).

Comment: What happens if you choose "Download the targeting pack..." and press `OK`?

Comment: I'm redirected to http://search.microsoft.com/en-GB/search.aspx

Comment: It does come in the box, pretty undiagnosable.  This profile is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile47.  Poke around a bit, see what other profiles you see in the parent directory.  Compare it to a colleague's machine.

Comment: I just checked on a fresh build VS2012 install from this morning and thats the location its installed.

Comment: All the profiles are installed correctly, but VS still complains, on two different machines. Using msbuild from command line gives a warning but works fine, though. But's it's much harder to debug problems when you're only able to use the command line

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? What Visual Studio Edition are you using (Express, Pro, etc)? What else was installed on the box (Phone tools)?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2012 Pro, and I also have the Windows Phone 8 SDK installed (but this also happens on another machine without the WP8 SDK installed)

Comment: It happened to me recently (C#), after doing some Google digging , not buying that I'm missing "anything?" selected the re-targeting to 4.5 proposal by VS...then using VSCommands selected convert to portable Library ...voila!.. no more problems .. please Note: the projects were already PCL

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently. It turned out that I was importing the wrong targets file at the bottom of the project.

To get it to work, I replaced it with this:

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.Portable.FSharp.Targets" />`

Comment: Another issue might be that this import is missing on disk - I suspect that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ZachBray pointed me at the problem. (after I got a project that wouldn't work)

I compared it with a new Portable Class Library and the problems is solved.

For most C# PCL's it the following line will work:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
```

(so at the end in the project file, replace the 'Import' element for this one or a newer one)