# F#: Is Profile 47 required for Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, f#, f#-data

This is a follow-up to [my post yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399773/f-fsc-error-fs2024-static-linking-may-not-use-assembly-that-targets-differen). To recap, I received this error message when trying to build my project:

> FSC: Error FS2024: Static linking may not use assembly that targets
>   different profile

I consulted some kind people in the F# [fpchat.com](http://fpchat.com/) channel, and one of them suggested that the error could be due to the fact that I did not have Profile 47, because FSharp.Data uses Profile 47. I tried downloading the target pack for Profile 47, but was redirected to the Microsoft homepage instead. I tried the second answer on [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935479/missing-targeting-pack-for-netframework-version-v4-0-profile-profile47), but that did not work either. As of now, I am still unable to acquire Profile 47.

I consulted the [FSharp.Data GitHub page](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data#supported-platforms), but it is not clear to me why Profile 47 is needed. I use VS2013 compiling to FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0; shouldn't that be sufficient, since the GitHub page lists it as one of the supported platforms?

I have created a new project, re-added all my source files and references, and tried re-building. I have even tried uninstalling and then re-installing Microsoft VS, even though I know it is likely irrelevant.

I think it is most probable that the problem lies with referencing FSharp.Data.TypeProviders. The error message does not appear insofar as I exclude reference to FSharp.Data.TypeProviders. The strangest thing is that I have not changed my references at all over the past week or so, but the error message only appeared yesterday.

So, my questions are:

1. Is Profile 47 really required? If so, how may I acquire it?
2. Even if I *do* acquire Profile 47, wouldn't I still experience trouble building my project, since my other references do not target Profile 47?
3. Are there any approaches that I may not have considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tearing my hair out trying a variety of suggested solutions I found online, I discovered that the only way to resolve the issue was to change my Target Framework from 4.5 to 4.0, re-install all of my references to ensure compatibility with .NET 4.0, and then re-build my solution. Using .NET 4.0 means that I am no longer able to use Microsoft.Experimental.Collections, since it is compatible only with .NET 4.5. This means that I will have to re-write all of my code that makes use of Microsoft.Experimental.Collections, but I consider that a lesser evil than not being able to build my project at all.

So, to answer my own question mentioned in the title, Profile 47 is not required to use FSharp.Data.TypeProviders. :-)

EDIT:

I have found another solution to my problem. I created a new project (again), migrated all my source files over, re-installed all the DLLs I need, and this time I have no trouble whatsoever building my project. I think Carsten (who wrote the first comment to this answer) is correct in saying that the versions became messed up in the original solution files.

Comment: well glad you found a solution (although I see no reason why it should not work with 4.5) - sometimes the stupid versions in the solution files get messed up - if you don't want to tear out your hairs by figuring them all out you can try to create a new solution and "add existing files" your old source files back in - it's tedious too but it saved me from time to time (usually a good source-control is even better - you probably can find out old/new versions and the reasons something changed it)

Comment: @Carsten, I don't see why it should not work with 4.5 either. In fact, I have been using 4.5 since the very beginning of my project, and I had no trouble at all with building my solution until yesterday. The problem literally just surfaced out of nowhere. I think I should look into getting a repo so that I can more easily debug if similar problems arise again in the future. :-)

Comment: @MY_G Yes, having a repo is *always* a good idea. Git has made it easy to have 'local only' source control, which is what I usually do when I start a new project. Migrating (and squashing the first detours) is really easy once the project is going public.